# MongoDB: how can I sort documents when querying with $or operator by conditions order?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, mongodb-query

Having the following Mongoose query:

```
User.find({$or: [
    { 'expertData.category': { $in: categoryIds } },
    { 'expertData.areas.category': { $in: categoryIds } }
]})
.limit(perPage)
.skip(perPage * page);
```

Fields `'expertData.category'` and `'expertData.areas.category'` are reference ids to `Category` collection, which has the following schema:

```
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    desc: {type: String},
    src : {type: String},
    updated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

Is there any way of sorting documents in a such way so at the beginning of the resulting array would be documents that are matching first condition in the `$or` operator (i.e. `{ '_expertData.category': { $in: categoryIds } }`) and only then would be all documents matching the second condition in the `$or` operator (i.e. `{ '_expertData.areas.category': { $in: categoryIds } }`)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you execute the commands separately and append the result from the second query to the result of the first query.

Comment: Yes, that's viable solution, but not in my case. I'm going to use `.limit` and `.skip` to paginate results. Sorry, that I didn't mention this in my original question. I've updated it now.